# Dimension problems

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. Prove that there exists a subspace 
$S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that verifies $\ker(f^2) = \ker(f) \bigoplus S$ and $\dim S = \dim f(S) \leq \dim(\ker(f))$.

**My attempt at solution:** So far I extended from the $\ker(f)$ to the $\ker(f^2)$ like this: let a base of $\ker(f)$ be $B = \{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ extending to a bae of $\ker(f^2)$ we get $B' = \{v_1,\ldots,v_r,v_{r+1},\ldots,v_m\}$. So I know that from $1$ to $r$ are elements linearly independent of $\ker(f)$, and from $r+1$ to $m$ I have my desired $S$. This verifies part of the second thing I'm asked, which is that $\dim S = \dim f(S)$, the thing is I'm having trouble with the inequality $\dim f(s) \leq \dim \ker(f)$. I've been trying to get the inequality using the dimension theorem but I cant seem to get it.

Comment: how do you know that $dim(ker(f^2))=n$ ??

Comment: my bad, thats m, not n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining $S$ to be the subspace with basis $\{v_{r+1}, \dots, v_m\}$, where $m \leq n$, right? The key property of this set is that $S \subset \ker(f^2)$ but $S$ is not in $\ker(f)$.  That means that if $w \in S$, then $f(w) \neq 0$ but $f(f(w)) = 0$.  Thus, $f(w) \in \ker(f)$.  You can conclude that $f(S) \subset \ker(f)$, which gives your inequality.